# Phonegap/ Android (java) - Moving a pre-populated SQLite Database + assets folder

Tags: java, android, sqlite, plugins, cordova

I am trying to copy my pre-populated database to a writable directory (I am thinking SD card), this needs to basically copy my whole assets folder within my phonegap android app.

I have done days of research and due to my very limited knowledge of java, I cannot seem to create this java plugin to do the simple copy and then from there I am not entirly certain how to actually call this plugin from my HTML/ Javascript.

Below is the current java plugin I have been working on using sample code found on the net, can someone please help guide me in the right direction.

JAVA PLUGIN:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;

    public class DataBaseHelper extends Plugin 
    {
    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) 
    {
        try
        {
            String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
            this.copy("Databases.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/");
            this.copy("0000000000000001.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/file__0/");
            }
                catch (IOException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String value = "OK";
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, value);
    }

    //Copy Paste this function in the class where you used above part
     void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
     {
         File CheckDirectory;
         CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
         if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
         { 
            CheckDirectory.mkdir();
         }

         InputStream in = this.ctx.getAssets().open(file);
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close(); out.close();            
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT PLUGIN CALL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="taxapp.js"></script>
function onDeviceReady() // CALLING THIS ON BODY LOAD
{
    dataCapture();
    window.plugins.DataBaseHelper.copy("",function(data)
    {
        alert("plugin called part 1");
        // nothing to do here
    },
    function()
    {
        alert("plugin called part 2");
        console.warn("Error calling plugin");
    }); 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I need to get this fixed today. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using already created Database with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `this.ctx` instead of `this` and `getApplicationContext()`, the `Plugin` isn't a Context in itself, but it holds the 'real' context in its `ctx` field.

Add a .js file with the content below:

```
var DataBaseHelper = function() {};

DataBaseHelper.prototype.copy = function(params, success, fail) 
{
    return PhoneGap.exec(function(args) 
    {
        success(args);
    }, 
    function(args) 
    {
        fail(args);
    }, 'DataBaseHelper', 'copy', [params]);
};



PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() 
{
    PhoneGap.addPlugin('DataBaseHelper', new DataBaseHelper());
    PluginManager.addService("DataBaseHelper","full.package.name.DataBaseHelper");
});
```

Then call the plugin anytime after PhoneGap is initialized:

```
window.plugins.DataBaseHelper.copy("",function(data)
{
    // nothing to do here
},
function()
{
    console.warn("Error calling plugin");
});
```

Also, after phonegap-1.0.0, you need a plugins.xml file in your res/xml directory, where you need to add:

```
<plugin name="DataBaseHelper" value="full.package.name.DataBaseHelper"/>
```

The best way to know if phonegap has initialized is by calling this method in javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() 
{
    //call your plugin here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix the that error, however I am not entirly sure how to call and execute this plugin within my HTML page. I add the javascript plugin section within the HTML page, and then need to call the plugin. How can this be done?

Comment: I have implemented your changed however it seems my database is still not copied across. I have edited my above code so you can see how I call the plugin. Thanks

Comment: As a side note I can manually push my database files within the simulator using DDMS and this works fine.

Comment: Is your execute method in the java Plugin called? Does it throw any errors? Maybe you need to add write permission to the manifest.

Comment: I believe it is called. I have edited my above code adding 2 lines within PluginResult. How can I check to see if any errors occur (The app loaded and installed error free ont he simulator and device). As for the permissions I already have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. your help is much appreciated, feel like im so close!

Comment: 1 other think to note, my 2 database files sit within my assets folder, so this basically contains ('www folder with all html js etc', '0000000000000001.db' and 'Databases.db').

Comment: I edited my post about onDeviceReady function, also add a try ... catch block and some log message to your copy method to see if it gets executed at all.

Comment: You are right about the plugin not loading have added loads of Log.d("PLUGIN WORKED", "it actually worked"); throughout my java. I for some reason cannot get the onDeviceReady to trigger, that is the reason that i was calling it from onLoad. I have noticed that the html javascript is not even being called (added alerts within both sections). Any other ideas?

Comment: See the last lines of my answer, maybe try adding it in this way, instead of calling onDeviceReady in the onLoad method.

Comment: That is exactly what i had used before, it seems to work fine on iOS and blackberry but not with Android, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using it on Android, make sure you add phonegap to your page first, then your plugin .js file.

Comment: I worked out why onDeviceReady was not working, I was using the iOS .js file ... durgh. However, it seems the plugin is not being called, it is called from the index.html page, but then I am not getting any messages or anything within Eclipses LogCat. Thanks

Comment: Thanks the above code works, however not for my scenario. This is due to my database being more than 1mb and running a OS older than 2.3.3. Therefore, I need to either upgrade my firmware or truncate the database. Thanks for the help.